# ReactNative Android :How to set text to image when using image in nested text

Tags: react-native

I used nested `Text` to add an `image` between the texts.
After that I tried to get the original `string` value but the `string` in the `image` is replaced with I.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TextInput,Button,Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: '',
    images:[],
  }


  changeText = (text) => {
    this.setState({
      text,
    });
  }

  parseText = () => {
    const { text,images } = this.state;
    if (images.length !== 0){
      return(
        <Text>
        {text}
        {images}
        </Text>
      );
    }
    return text;
  }

  addImage = () => {
    const { images } = this.state;
    const newImage = (<Image
        style={{width:20,height:20}}
       source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')} />);
    this.setState({
      images:[...images , newImage],
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <TextInput
       style={{flex:1}}
       onChangeText={this.changeText}
       placeholder="test"
       >
       {this.parseText()}
       </TextInput>
       <Button
        title="add Image"
        onPress={this.addImage}
       />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

> https://snack.expo.io/rkjP70hUS

This example is intended to illustrate the approximate situation but not the same as mine.

In this example, when you add an image and import text, the image comes out as I.
Can I change to the string  instead of I?

Comment: Could you please elaborate some? Do you want to set a custom image to a button or to show text over an image.

Comment: @AbdulBasit 
I want to implement a custom emoticon with Slack or FaceBook.

When put an image in a TextInput and send it to the server,
It should look like `Text <ImageName> Text`
But when I edit the text, <ImageName> changes to I.